# How to add Assets to a Flex Library?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to add assets into a flex library .swc file with no success.

The assets folder in the library project contains a gif file. The project also contains a Spark Group componnent that displays the image.

When i try to use this componnent in a different project the image is not visible. 
If i copy the assets folder from the library project to the main project the image is visible.

I added the assets folder in the Flex Library Build Path

Why aren't the assets contained by the swc?

Thank you!

Attached screenshots: [image] [image]

Comment: I suspect that the image is included in the SWC; but is not included in the SWF that uses the SWC.  A SWC is a zip file so you can unzip it to see if your image is in there.  If you aren't embedding the asset; I suspect the Flex compiler won't put it in your resulting SWF.

Comment: Did you found answer? Alternative would be to add assets source folder as one of project sources, so you can pick files in 'Package Contents', right?

Answer (score 2):

Create class in library project

```
package resources
{
    public final class IconResource
    {
        //list embedded items - you can embed any files, mp3 etc

        [Embed (source="../assets/facebook.gif" )]
        public static const icon_facebook:Class;    

        public function IconResource()
        {}
    }
}
```

Using in production projects:

```
import resources.IconResource;

var img:Image = new Image();
img.source = IconResource.icon_facebook;
```

or

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    import resources.IconResource;
  ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Image source="{IconResource.icon_facebook}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're trying to access the image from the library.

For it to work, you need to use @Embed("facebook.gif") in your case - no "assets" folder used in path. So, you won't be able to access it from your application unless you embed it, and you only use the name of the file for embedding.

Comment: i use the image only in the library project within an mxml image componnent. I then use the componnent in the main project

Comment: If you set the source on the image component to be the path to the image, it won't work. You need to set it to an embed. Because the image will be included in the SWC, but you won't be able to use via a path to it. That's pretty much what I'm trying to say in my answer.